# Prevent html injection on Asp.Net textbox validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

**I want to add a validator which prevents the html injection on Asp.Net injection. I am using the below code :**

<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBoxMultiLine" runat="server" TagName="textBoxValidation" Width="50%" AutoPostBack="False" autocomplete="off" textMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="HTML Tags Not Allowed" ControlToValidate="TxtBoxMultiLine" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateTitle" ValidationGroup="htmlValidation"></asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:Button Text="Save" ID="addSaveBttn" CssClass="savesimpleshape1" runat="server" OnClick="addSaveBttn_Click" ValidationGroup="htmlValidation"/>

***i am using that javascript function to validate my textbox.***

```
    function ValidateTitle(event) {
        str = (document.getElementById('textBoxValidation')).value;
      if (str.match(/([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i) == null) {            
          event.IsValid = true;
      }
      else {        
          event.IsValid = false;
      }
  }
```

**When i pressed the button occurs that exception : *A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client***

**It seems that is ignoring my validation. Also, i don't want to put this element : ValidateRequest = false on my page.**

Answer (score 1):

You may use client script like:

```
 function ValidateTitle(event,args) {
        str = (document.getElementById('textBoxValidation')).value;
      if (str.match(/([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i) == null) {            
          args.IsValid = true;
      }
      else {        
          args.IsValid = false;
      }
  }
```

and

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="HTML Tags Not Allowed" ControlToValidate="TxtBoxMultiLine" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateTitle" ValidationGroup="htmlValidation" EnableClientScript="true" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

You could correct some errors.

```
str = (document.getElementById('textBoxValidation')).value;
```

to

```
  str = (document.getElementById('TxtBoxMultiLine')).value;
```

You must set all input to some validation group

and you must add a script resource for WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery' error. also your regex not complately detect html code you change your regex from

```
 if (str.match(/([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i) == null) {
```

to

```
  if (str.match("<[^>]*>") == null) {
```

may you need more complex regex.

Comment: It returns me the same exception. It looks that before the execution of onclick action, the mechanism has recognized the html tags and it blocks me.

Comment: @Fatman123 Your text box not in validation group.

Comment: I removed the validation group from all tags and occurs the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the exception: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client  Add the below inside the `<system.web>` element.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri"/>
```

After validating your input, the below will strip HTML tags in a textbox using regex.

```
const rx = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
const result = str.replace(rx, "");
```